# I'm trying to pass dynamic values to an .html file before sending it as an attachment using Phpmailer

Tags: php, dynamic, phpmailer, email-attachments

I'm trying to send an .html file as an attachment using PHP-mailer, however, I want to dynamically modify some values in the file before it's added and sent. I'm not sure if my logic is okay but the email is sending but it's not sending with an attachment.
Below is my code sample.

```
    for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['attachment']['name']); $i++) {
    if ($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'][$i] != ""){   
        $templateFile = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
        $attStr = file_get_contents($templateFile);
        $attStrNew = str_replace("[-email-]" ,$email, $attStr );
        $templateFile = file_put_contents($attStr, $attStrNew);
        $mail->AddAttachment($templateFile[$i],$_FILES['attachment']['name'][$i]);
       }
   }
```

Comment: Yes, I know something is wrong from that side but can you help modify the code?

Comment: Please how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file_put_contents()` arguments seem to be wrong. First argmument is file name, and I don't think you want `$attStr` to be the filename. Also it returns the number of bytes written or false and sets `$templateFile` to it.

Here is a rewrite with a cleaner approach:

- create an array for tmp files
- go thru all attachments
- read the template file
- replace the template variables
- write the new content into a new tmp file
- collect the tmp file name to delete after sending
- set the tmp file as attachment

```
$tmpFiles = [];
foreach ($_FILES['attachment']['name'] as $filename) {
    if (empty($filename)) {
        continue;
    }
    $content  = file_get_contents($filename);
    $content  = str_replace("[-email-]", $email, $content);
    $tmpFilename = tempnam("/tmp", 'attachment');
    $tmpFiles[] = $tmpFilename;
    file_put_contents($tmpFilename, $content);
    $mail->AddAttachment($tmpFilename, $filename);
}

// send the mail and then delete the tmp files.

array_walk($tmpFiles, 'unlink');
```

Comment: This code is unsafe, and goes against the advice in [the PHP docs on handling uploads](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php). Validate your uploads with `move_uploaded_file` before trusting the `$_FILES` array. Also, `addAttachment()` returns a boolean that tells you whether it worked or not. Look at [the file upload example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps) for how to handle uploads correctly.

Comment: It is not intended to keep the uploaded files. That's why `move_uploaded_file()` is not used.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you keep them afterwards – you are keeping them for long enough for potential damage to be done. As it stands you're using untrusted, unvalidated, user-supplied data from both filename and contents.

Comment: The whole thing itself is unsafe and I would not use that in production at all.

Comment: So why suggest it?